# cout return twice a string of char

Tags: c++, g++

The output of the below code is

```
Toto
TotoToto
```

but I would hope just

```
Toto
Toto
```

**Why the second cout repeat the string in the output?**

I'm using g++ version 7.5.0 on Ubuntu, I'm not sure if this is relevant.

The code is the following:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  char c1[] = "Toto";
  char c2[4] = {'T','o','t','o'};


  cout << c1 << endl;
  cout << c2 << endl;


  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you stream out a character array, it must - by convention - be null terminated, otherwise you have *undefined behaviour*.

Change `c2` as follows and it will start working as hoped:

```
char c2[5] = {'T','o','t','o', '\0'};
```

In the case of `c1`, it assumes you'll want an implicit null appended and sizes `c1` automatically to allow space for that, so if you use [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) or [`std::extent<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) to get the size of `c1` you'll see it's 5 bytes.

Drew's comment suggests explaining about the decay of arrays to pointers when calling functions, so here goes.  When you write:

```
cout << c2;
```

The compiler calls the function `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*)`.  The array `c2` *decays* to a `char*`, allowing the function to be matched and called, but in doing so all knowledge of the text length is lost.  The function implementation expects you to follow the convention of having a null terminator after the text to be streamed.  If you want explicit control of how many characters should be printed, you can use e.g. `std::cout.write(c2, 3)`.  `std::string`s also work more intuitively - beginning programmers should prefer using `std::string`s to store and manipulate text.

Comment: You may want to note that `std::cout` has no overload for a "character array".  The array must decay to a `const char*`, which is why a terminator is needed.  **Edit:** doubly so, given the comment below this one.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved.

But philosophically, why will it be like this? Why don't you understand that the last character is always null, and if it doesn't exist, repeat the string? Has anyone any intuition? In the worse case I could expect that, I do not write \0 at the end, then the system could put there any trash, but the system repeat the char, Why do you think this occurs?

Comment: @user106306 Probably, your compiler placed `c2` just before `c1` on the stack which leads to your stack looking like `TotoToto\0` starting with `c2[0]`. It makes it looks like `&c2[0]` points to a null terminated character string that contains 8 characters before the null terminator. Edit : Since this is Undefined Behavior, the output of your program can change at any time for no apparent reason. You can't rely on this layout always being true.

Comment: @user106306: _undefined behaviour_ can manifest in many ways.  In this case, it may have repeated the string because it found you had two strings `"Toto"` and `"Toto\0"` in your program, and happened to allocate them in that order in memory, so when it overran the array `c2` trying to print each character, if flowed back into `c1` and printed `Toto` again.  If you change one of the strings, you may observe that.  But, trying to reason about _undefined behaviour_ is a doomed exercise - just have to avoid it.